# How to handle list of tibbles in R and their content?

Tags: r, list, missing-data, tibble

Let's consider the following R code only for exemplification purpose:

```
X <- tibble(v0=seq( as.Date("2011-07-01"), by=1, len=6),v1 = c(1,-1,2,1,2,-1), v2 = replicate(6, 0), v3 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), v4 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), v5 = replicate(6, 0))
Y <- tibble(v0=seq( as.Date("2011-07-01"), by=1, len=6),v1 = c(1,1,2,1,2,1), v2 = c(1,NA,2,1,NA,1), v3 = c(NA,NA,3,NA,5,NA), v4 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), v5 = replicate(6, 0))
dataset <- list(X,Y)
names(dataset) <- c("X","Y")
dataset

$X
# A tibble: 6 × 6
  v0            v1    v2 v3    v4       v5
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <lgl> <dbl>
1 2011-07-01     1     0 NA    NA        0
2 2011-07-02    -1     0 NA    NA        0
3 2011-07-03     2     0 NA    NA        0
4 2011-07-04     1     0 NA    NA        0
5 2011-07-05     2     0 NA    NA        0
6 2011-07-06    -1     0 NA    NA        0

$Y
# A tibble: 6 × 6
  v0            v1    v2    v3 v4       v5
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <dbl>
1 2011-07-01     1     1    NA NA        0
2 2011-07-02     1    NA    NA NA        0
3 2011-07-03     2     2     3 NA        0
4 2011-07-04     1     1    NA NA        0
5 2011-07-05     2    NA     5 NA        0
6 2011-07-06     1     1    NA NA        0
```

I would like to:

1. Set all the cols except the first for X and Y as numeric;
2. Set all negative values to zeros (both for X and Y, even if Y does not have any);

This should result in element(2,2) and element(6,2) equals zero for the first tibble.

3. Exclude from all the dataset cols with all `NA` or all zero values in three different cases:

a. `dataset_a` variables that does not have any complete missing value or zeros column (in the example `dataset_a` equals the dates and `v1`);

b. `dataset_b` variables that does not have all missing value or zeros column across the dataset (in the example `dataset_a` equals the dates and `v1,v2,v3`);

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

new_dataset <- lapply(dataset, function(d) {
  
  d %>% 
    mutate(
      across(-1, as.numeric), # condition 1
      across(where(is.numeric), ~pmax(., 0)) # condition 2
    ) %>% 
    select(where(~!all(is.na(.x) | .x == 0))) # condition 3
  
})

$X
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  v0            v1
  <date>     <dbl>
1 2011-07-01     1
2 2011-07-02     0
3 2011-07-03     2
4 2011-07-04     1
5 2011-07-05     2
6 2011-07-06     0

$Y
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  v0            v1    v2    v3
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2011-07-01     1     1    NA
2 2011-07-02     1    NA    NA
3 2011-07-03     2     2     3
4 2011-07-04     1     1    NA
5 2011-07-05     2    NA     5
6 2011-07-06     1     1    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `dplyr` approach, which also employs `lapply` to go through the list elements.

Two data frames (`dataset_a` and `dataset_b`) are created in the global environment.

```
library(dplyr)

setNames(lapply(dataset, function(x) 
  mutate(x, across(-1, ~ifelse(.x < 0, 0L, as.integer(.x)))) %>% 
    select(where(~ any(. != 0, na.rm = T)))), c("dataset_a", "dataset_b")) %>% 
  list2env(envir = .GlobalEnv)

dataset_a
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  v0            v1
  <date>     <int>
1 2011-07-01     1
2 2011-07-02     0
3 2011-07-03     2
4 2011-07-04     1
5 2011-07-05     2
6 2011-07-06     0

dataset_b
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  v0            v1    v2    v3
  <date>     <int> <int> <int>
1 2011-07-01     1     1    NA
2 2011-07-02     1    NA    NA
3 2011-07-03     2     2     3
4 2011-07-04     1     1    NA
5 2011-07-05     2    NA     5
6 2011-07-06     1     1    NA
```